# Numbered Countries

Tags: knowledge, pattern, geography

I've assigned numbers to several European nations as shown below. My question is: what's my methodology in choosing these numbers? What would the numbers for Estonia, Latvia, and Lithuania be?

(Note: I may have made a mistake, in which case I am sorry.)

Portugal: 90

Spain: 90

United Kingdom: 32

The Netherlands: 35

Norway: 105

Sweden: 45

Belarus: 95

Bulgaria: 87

Armenia: 117

Russia: 127

I will periodically release hints with more countries and numbers.

Hint 1

> Italy: 90.

Comment: (Note: I may have made a mistake, in which case I am sorry.) Deliberate?

Comment: @ManojKumar hopefully my nunbers are accurate but there is a chance that I missed something.

Comment: Something to do with R-Ebnq Argjbex?

Comment: Then Fvkgl Frira can be the missing number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is probably

> Estonia - 77 (initial wrong answer: 67), Latvia - 77, Lithuania - 85

That's because

> This number of a country is the largest "main" [European road](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_E-road_network) number (numbered Exx (xx=01 to 99) or E1xx (xx=01 to 29)) which runs through that country.

I've figured it

> just being a fan of Euro Truck Simulator 2 game, and so memorising some E-road numbers which run through certain countries.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Wait, I have just realized that one of your numbers is wrong, though i will still accept this answer since you got the method. Rot13(Gur R-friragl frira oneryl ragref rfgbavn)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer, now it's probably correct.